# How to memory-map a PCI BAR using PCIDriverKit?

Tags: c++, macos, iokit, driverkit, macos-system-extension

How to memory-map a PCI Base Address Register (BAR) from a PCIDriverKit driver (DEXT) to a userspace application?

Memory-mapping from a driver extension to an application can be accomplished by implementing the [IOUserClient::CopyClientMemoryForType](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/driverkit/iouserclient/3325615-copyclientmemoryfortype) in the user client subclass (on the *driver* side) and then calling [IOConnectMapMemory64](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/iokit/1514862-ioconnectmapmemory64) (from the *user-space application* side). This has been very nicely and thoroughly explained in [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62214463/536113).

The only missing bit is getting an [IOMemoryDescriptor](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/kernel/iomemorydescriptor) corresponding to the desired PCI BAR in order to return it from the `CopyClientMemoryForType` implementation.

#### Sample code

Asked another way, given the following simplified code, what would be the implementation of `imaginaryFunctionWhichReturnsTheBARBuffer`?

```cpp
kern_return_t IMPL(MyUserClient, CopyClientMemoryForType) //(uint64_t type, uint64_t *options, IOMemoryDescriptor **memory)
{
    IOMemoryDescriptor* buffer = nullptr;
    
    imaginaryFunctionWhichReturnsTheBARBuffer(ivars->pciDevice /* IOPCIDevice */, kPCIMemoryRangeBAR0, &buffer);

    *memory = buffer;

    return kIOReturnSuccess;
}
```

In the previous code `ivars->pciDevice` refers to a ready-to-use [IOPCIDevice](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/pcidriverkit/iopcidevice) (e.g.: it has been succesfully matched, opened and configured according to [latest best practices](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10210/)).

This means it's already possible to use the various [configuration](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/kernel/iopcidevice/3516624-configurationread32) and [memory](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/kernel/iopcidevice/3516643-memoryread64) read/write methods to access explicit offsets from the desired PCI BAR memory. What's missing (or unclear) is how to use those APIs (or equivalent ones) to **map the entire buffer corresponding to a PCI BAR** to a user-space application.

#### Random notes that might or might not be relevant

- [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62214463/536113) from the related question: [How to allocate memory in a DriverKit system extension and map it to another process?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62213115/536113) contains the following quote:

  > [...] The returned memory descriptor need not be an IOBufferMemoryDescriptor as I've used in the example, it can also be a PCI BAR or whatever.

  This is *exactly* what I want to do, so at least it sounds like it should be possible. The only remaining question is *how* to implement it.
- [A similar question](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/662279) has been posted on the Apple forums and even though it hasn't received any answers yet (as of the time of this writing), it does contain some useful pointers.

  It looks like there is a **private** function  in PCIDriverKit with the following signature:

  ```cpp
  virtual kern_return_t IOPCIDevice::_CopyDeviceMemoryWithIndex(uint64_t memoryIndex, IOMemoryDescriptor** memory, IOService* forClient)
  ```

  It's hard to tell what it's supposed to do exactly (since it is undocumented), but the signature does seem to match with the function I'm looking for. However, trying to use it always results in an error code (similar to the one reported in the original forum post). The error code seems to be different depending on which argument is passed as `IOService *forClient`).

  Another good point from that post is that there is a [getDeviceMemoryWithIndex](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/kernel/ioservice/1809999-getdevicememorywithindex) available to kernel extensions (KEXT) which could be used to accomplish what we need (*if* the driver was implemented as a PCI kernel extension which seems to be deprecated now).

  However, this function doesn't seem to be available to driver extensions (DEXT). So another question of framing this question could be: What's the equivalent `getDeviceMemoryWithIndex` for PCIDriverKit driver extensions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out `IOPCIDevice::_CopyDeviceMemoryWithIndex` was indeed the function needed to implement this (but the fact that it's private is still an inconvenient).

#### Sample code

Bellow is some sample code showing how this could be implemented (the code uses `MyDriver` for the driver class name and `MyDriverUserClient` for the user client).

Relevant sections from `MyDriver.cpp` implementation:

```cpp
struct MyDriver_IVars {
    IOPCIDevice* pciDevice = nullptr;
};

// MyDriver::init/free/Start/Stop/NewUserClient implementation ommited for brevity

IOMemoryDescriptor* MyDriver::copyBarMemory(uint8_t barIndex)
{
    IOMemoryDescriptor* memory;
    uint8_t barMemoryIndex, barMemoryType;
    uint64_t barMemorySize;

    // Warning: error handling is omitted for brevity
    ivars->pciDevice->GetBARInfo(barIndex, &barMemoryIndex, &barMemorySize, &barMemoryType);
    ivars->pciDevice->_CopyDeviceMemoryWithIndex(barMemoryIndex, &memory, this);

    return memory;
}
```

Relevant sections from `MyDriverUserClient.cpp` implementation:

```cpp
struct MyDriverUserClient_IVars {
    MyDriver* myDriver = nullptr;
};

// MyDriverUserClient::init/free/Start/Stop implementation ommited for brevity

kern_return_t
IMPL(MyDriverUserClient, CopyClientMemoryForType) //(uint64_t type, uint64_t *options, IOMemoryDescriptor **memory)
{
    *memory = ivars->myDriver->copyBARMemory(kPCIMemoryRangeBAR0);

    return kIOReturnSuccess;
}
```

#### Additional Resources

A complete implementation that uses this pattern can be found in the [ivshmem.dext](https://github.com/vially/ivshmem.dext) project (which implements a macOS driver for [IVSHMEM](https://github.com/qemu/qemu/blob/5012e522aca161be5c141596c66e5cc6082538a9/docs/specs/ivshmem-spec.rst)).

Comment: Are you sure this works on ARM64 based Macs? I was under the impression that memory-mapping BARs wasn't possible there.

Comment: That's a very good point and you may be right but unfortunately I don't have an arm64 mac to test this on. For my use-case (the linked IVHSMEM driver), I'm running macOS on an x64 virtual machine and it seems to work fine.

Comment: @pmdj Do you happen to know an alternative way to do this memory mapping that would work on arm64 mac too? Or maybe there is some other way of copying large amounts of memory to and from a PCI BAR? I'm all very new to these topics and I've been scrambling to come up with a good solution for this that works everywhere (and ideally without resorting to private APIs).


By the way, I was secretly hoping you'd pop by and provide an answer since you seem to be the authority on these issues on Stack Overflow. Thanks for all the valuable information you are providing on these topics!

Comment: Having ported some kexts to arm64e, the only BAR accesses I could find are the [`MemoryRead*` and `MemoryWrite*` family of methods on `IOPCIDevice`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/pcidriverkit/iopcidevice). To be fair this makes sense in terms of what's happening on the bus as far as I'm aware. If your device is expecting to exchange large amounts of data via BARs, this is unfortunate, because that's really what DMA is for. And DMA works as before on ARM. (`IODMACommand` etc.)

Comment: (I'm not deeply familiar with how the IVSHMEM device works, though glancing at the spec, it appears that DMA is indeed not supported. Strange choice given that virtio devices for example are heavily DMA based.)

Comment: That makes sense. In that case I might open an issue with the QEMU project and see if there are any plans to add support for DMA to the IVSHMEM device. Thanks again for your input!

Comment: I suspect it might not even be that hard to write a patch to Qemu implementing this as an optional mode of operation. (I've written the odd patch to Qemu myself.)